Change in behaviour of Notepad++ plugins Compare and ComparePlus
The warning is: "Trying to compare files with different encodings - the result might be inaccurate and misleading. Compare anyway?"
The two files I'm comparing have been outputted from the same script. The output from the script is via
# Write to file
($street | Out-String).Trim() | Add-Content -Path $filesPathAdminElectorateStreets -Encoding UTF8

The only difference is the filename e.g file.txt & file1.txt
Functionality is normal from this point on.
Why am I receiving this message? Can you suggest a fix or workaround?

The issue is the Powershell version being used by my Visual Studio Code IDE. My VS Code was running an old version of PS (5.1) I was switching to the latest (7.4.4) manually in VS Code. This was the trap I set myself. I overlooked the fact that I had been doing this when I saved different versions of the same text file. The encodings were different for these two files because each was saved with a different version of PS.
